# Return Id of selected row in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

i have below table and i want to select the total Quantity 20 of SKU 001A and also want to return the ids of rows from where quantity will be selected.

```
Id   SKU    QtyRec  QtyDispatch
 1    001A    5          0
 2    001B    5          0
 3    001C    10         0
 4    001A    8          0
 5    001G    5          0
 6    001A    6          0
 7    001F    5          0
 8    001A    25         0
 9    001A    9          0
```

The quantity 5 of SKU 001A will be selected from id 1, 8 quantity from id 4, 6 Quantity from id 6 and 1 quantity from id 8 to complete the require quantity 20.
I try to explain the whole scenario and in case of any concern please let me know. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Data table (Id int identity(1,1), SKU varchar(10), QtyRec int)
DECLARE @Qty int = 20

INSERT @Data VALUES
('001A', 5 ),
('001B', 5 ),
('001C', 10),
('001A', 8 ),
('001G', 5 ),
('001A', 6 ),
('001F', 5 ),
('001A', 25),
('001A', 9 )

;WITH sumqty AS 
(
  SELECT *, SUM(QtyRec) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id) AS TotalQty 
  FROM @Data WHERE SKU = '001A'
)
,takeqty AS (
  SELECT *, 
    CASE 
      WHEN @Qty >= TotalQty THEN QtyRec 
      ELSE @Qty - ISNULL(LAG(TotalQty) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id), 0) -- for single entry of SKU
    END AS TakeQty
   FROM sumqty
)
SELECT * FROM takeqty WHERE TakeQty > 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2543)

Comment: hey...I just make some change ...like I insert new SKU='001E' with QtyRec=60 when I try to take out  20 quantity of SKU='001E'  it select nothing.... your help will be really appreciate able.

Comment: @AlinaDilshad Opps, the query is incorrect for only one entry of data, please see edit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2543

Comment: Hey Eric...Thanks for your Help...One thing more i want to do that i want to make selection of Quantity from those SKU who is going to expire first. For reference i have example on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9941/1/0

Comment: @AlinaDilshad Just change it to `ORDER BY Expiry` instead of `ORDER BY Id` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72/282